# Javascript 2D array - best way to initialize with values

Tags: javascript, arrays, nested, copy

I'm trying to create a 2D array `visited` to show where the code has already visited in the `grid`. The way I have it now is that each row in `visited` is a shallow copy. Changing the value in one row, changes in all of the rows. What's the best way to initialize the starting values in `visited` in this case?

```
let grid = 
  [
    ["0", "1", "0"],
    ["1", "0", "1"],
    ["0", "1", "0"],
  ]

let visited = new Array(grid.length).fill(new Array(grid[0].length).fill(false))

visited[0][1]= true

console.log(visited);
```

Output:

```
[
  [ false, true, false ],
  [ false, true, false ],
  [ false, true, false ]
]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use map to create new array for each row

```js
let grid = 
  [
    ["0", "1", "0"],
    ["1", "0", "1"],
    ["0", "1", "0"],
  ]

let visited = Array.from({length: grid.length}, () => Array(grid[0].length).fill(false))

visited[0][1]= true

console.log(visited);
```

Also you can replace `new Array()` with `Array.from`

i.e `Array.from({length: grid.length}, () => Array(grid[0].length).fill(false))`

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me. Would you mind explaining why? On MDN, it says that `from` creates a shallow copy. The inner function of `Array(grid[0].length).fill(false)` was also how I created the array originally too

Comment: fill places the same value at all the indexes of array, so when you do this `fill(new Array(grid[0].length)` it places same array at all indexes, so now all indexes is referring to same index. whereas callback in from method works more as map.